# Docker Gitlab pre-configure settings for projects limit

Tags: docker, gitlab

I am trying to build a Docker container (based on the gitlab-ce (version 8.9.6) Docker image) where when the container is created, the user does NOT have to go into the gitlab web interface and modify the settings to change default project size limit from 10 to 100. I have the automation designed to import (rake) all the repos once container is created, but unless I can have the project size limit setting changed from 10 to 100 before container creation, it fails to import all the required repos. Need the user to have NO input to set up the gitlab container: 1) NO launching web browser to adjust settings and 2) NO typing of sudo password on host machine in a script (as we can't depend on the user having sudo privilege). I don't see any setting in the gitlab.rb file that can handle changing the project limit size.

Currently, I have tried:

**Attempt 1:**

- go in to the container, in to the Gitlab web interface
- change the user admin settings (project size limit from 10 to 100)
- commit the container as a new image
- launch a new container based off the new image
- **FAILS** as the settings aren't persistent in new image

**Attempt 2:**

- go in to the container, in to the Gitlab web interface
- change the user admin settings (project size limit from 10 to 100)
- copy out the gitlab volume mounts (/etc/gitlab, /var/log/gitlab, and /var/opt/gitlab) to host location
- create a new container using these directories as a volume mount
- run docker exec -it gitlab update-permissions
- **FAILS** As I can't keep the same in-container permissions on host (would require sudo) and the update-permissions command doesn't work.
- **SUCCEEDS** Only when I keep the container permissions the same on host (using sudo permissions), which is not what I am looking for.

Does anyone know of a way to set the project limit size setting of the docker gitlab image on launching of a container? Or, be able to have these settings be persistent into a new image/container without using sudo?

Thanks!